# Is there any better approach for multiple site testing where data is coming from the excel sheet?

Tags: java, selenium, maven, apache-poi, testng

I do have more than 50 e-commerce websites where I want to test multiple features i.e login, register, add to cart, checkout etc using my selenium , Java and testng Framework.

I am kind of confuse in choosing best approach to do it because I am looking for setup where Once I run the test, it should go to each website one by one, complete the testing and move to next.

For now I choose `testng Dataprovider` but that seems not something which could help. I am getting all the rows / data from the excel but can't split data for the different functions which is stopping me to use data provider.

For example My excel contains all the rows :

```
Url | Username | Password | Productname | creditcard number | shipping address
```

And my test class has different method for each purpose

```
public void login(String username, String password)
public void addtoCart(String prodcutName)
public void FillTheCreditCard(String cardNumber)
```

But as per design of testng Dataprovider I can not use only few parameters from the excel sheet as per my need, I have to pass all into function even if not needed (which I feel is not good practice).

so now I am giving up from the `testng data provider`. and looking for better way to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

What I assume you'd want is to get an array containing all the cell contents for each column, which you can go with `jxl`. I've come up with (and not tested) the following to grab what's in your "Url" column:

```
import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;

...

File f=new File("C:\\Users\\data.xls");
Workbook Wb=Workbook.getWorkbook(f);
Sheet sh=Wb.getSheet(0);
int row=sh.getRows();
String[] urlArray = []

for (int i=0;i<row;i++){
    Cell c=sh.getCell(0,i);
    urlArray = Arrays.copyOf(urlArray, urlArray.length + 1);
    urlArray[urlArray.length - 1] = c.getContents()
```